# Как мне указать ID в чате?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Получаю ошибку

ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400 Description: Bad Request: chat not found

При запуске функции

```
def send_messange():
    return bot.send_message(chat_id, "some text")
```

Comment: В ошибке написано в чем причина: `chat not found`

Comment: И что мне делать?

Comment: Оно не работает как не крути

Comment: Указывать id существующего чата. Когда ваш бот получает сообщение, из него можно получить chat_id. Если это приватный чат, т.е. диалог бота и юзера, то chat_id соответствует user_id, т.е. id пользователя. Еще, боту нужно написать, насколько я помню, бот не может отправить сообщение юзеру, если тот не начинал общение с ботом

Answer (score 2):

Ответ очень прост. В функцию, которая оборачивается декоратором нужно передать один аргумент, принято писать `message`, вы его упустили. Исходя из `json`-объекта `message` - там содержится и идентификатор пользователя. По нему можно достучаться в `pytelegrambotapi` таким способом:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    print(message)  # ознакомьтесь, что находится в этом `json`-объекте 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Some text")
```

Comment: Проблема не в этом, мне надо указать эту функцию в Scedule

Comment: Так вы привели вопрос с ошибкой `Error code: 400 Description: Bad Request: chat not found `, а не про `schedule`. Чтобы внести правки в вопрос, воспользуйтесь кнопкой "Править"

Answer (score 0):

Пример хендлера:

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def echo(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
```

Настоятельно рекомендую почитать [документацию к библиотеке](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#general-api-documentation) и [API телеграмма](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api).